# Grub errors during UEFI dual boot for Windows 8 (can't find command 'drivemap')

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, uefi

I have got a newly bought ASUS N56V with Windows 8 preinstalled.

I needed to install Ubuntu so i partitioned the disk and after having disabled the Secure Boot option from Windows 8 i successfully installed Ubuntu 12.10 from a Live USB. The problem is that if i try to access both to `Windows 8 (loader)` and `Windows Recovery System (loader)` from the GRUB menu, these two errors show: `can't find command 'drivemap'` and `invalid EFI file path` and it goes back to the grub menu.

In conclusion I do not have access to my Windows 8 partition but can only use Ubuntu. How can I solve the problem? I am pretty new to the matter.

Thank you!

Comment: Hello I had the same problem.[See my question and my answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/233687/windows-8-and-ubuntu-12-10-dual-boot-on-uefi/235519#235519)

Comment: Here is a useful [tutorial with images](http://www.simplehelp.net/2013/07/10/how-to-fix-the-cant-find-command-drivemap-error-after-installing-ubuntu/), it doesn't fix my problem, but it's worth giving a try.

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue as well. I followed the instructions here:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB2#Microsoft_Windows_installed_in_UEFI-GPT_mode

The curveball is that I could not edit grub.cfg directly, as on my machine it is generated by the grub-mkconfig command. I added the 'menuentry "Windows ..." { ... }' to /etc/grub.d/40_custom

The downside is that the windows entry that works is below all the windows entries that don't. But the upside is that one of the windows entries works, so I'll live with it.

Comment: You are right, modifying `40_custom` instead of `grub.cfg` is recommended. I want to note that it is not necessary to have the Windows boot loader and configuration in the EFI System Partition when booting UEFI GRUB with this method. This way, having a Windows MBR install with `/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi` on C: (run `bcdboot C:\Windows /s C: /f uefi` and look up bcdboot documentation for more details) and a Ubuntu UEFI install also works when the custom entry is modified accordingly (e.g. `insmod part_msdos`; `insmod ntfs`; `set root='hd0,msdos4'`).