# (U)EFI > Ubuntu vs Windows 8 - problems with booting Windows

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-8, uefi

I have a problem with a screwed dual-boot of ubuntu 13.04 and windows 8 on a new DELL XPS 12 (EFI/grub2) System not loading windows8 at all,... here is a story:

I've got a new DELL XPS 12 System with preinstalled Windows8 on (U)EFI Firmware (I have never dealt with EFI before).

There are 5-6 partitions over there :

- EFI
- Windows 8
- Hibernate
- Ubuntu 13.04
- Windows Data
- Repair

but it worked as expected for few weeks.

I decided then to install a new Ubuntu 13.04 x64 on top of Windows8 with dual boot.
Somehow (don't ask) I screwed Windows 8 partitions and got only a new Ubuntu installed on a new partition I've created before but lost the access/boot as well as a way to read any of the NTFS Windows partitions I had.
I tried to fix that all during the next few days by using TestDisk, BootRepair and few other tools quite successfully and now I am close to a final solution yet not there, needing some help.

Here is the actual situation:

- Ubuntu 13.04 x64 installed and working as expected with grub2 loader
- From ubuntu I'have all the NTFS partitions readable so my Windows 8 and Windows Data partition are there
- On computer boot in EFI mode (NO secureboot though) grub2 loads and Ubuntu starts up with no issues
- The problem is that Windows8 does NOT boot from grub2 stating "...EFI" file not found
- Comparing the issues with some others I've read here seems I have Windows 8 EFI file screwed as my bootx64 and bootmdfw efis are 121KB big and not 1.3MB as some reported/supposed for Windows 8
- Boot-Repair does not help neither does win8 repair liveUSB wit bootxxx /fixmbr /fixboot  options whatsoever

Here are my Boot-Repair paste file as well as list of my actual partitions/efi files...

boot-repair report --> http://paste.ubuntu.com/5668969/

```
list of partitions
------------------
             Partition    Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors System
EFI        > /dev/sda1           2,048     1,026,047     1,024,000 EFI System partition
Win8-OS    > /dev/sda2       1,026,048   132,098,047   131,072,000 EFI System partition
Win8-Hyber > /dev/sda3     132,098,048   150,530,047    18,432,000 EFI System partition
Ubuntu 13.4> /dev/sda4     150,530,048   236,510,511    85,980,464 Data partition (Windows/Linux)
Win8-Data  >/dev/sda5     236,513,280   500,118,157   263,604,878 Data partition (Windows/Linux)
------------------

list efi files
--------------
/boot/efi:
total 5
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  512 gen  1  1970 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 mag  8 10:09 ..
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root  512 mag 14 01:25 EFI

/boot/efi/EFI:
total 3
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 512 mag 14 01:25 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 512 gen  1  1970 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 512 mag 13 17:02 Boot
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 512 mag 14 01:25 Microsoft
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 512 mag  6 10:18 ubuntu

/boot/efi/EFI/Boot:
total 239
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    512 mag 13 17:02 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root    512 mag 14 01:25 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 121856 mag 13 17:02 bootx64.efi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      0 mag 13 17:02 bootx64.efi.grb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 121856 mag  8 10:09 bootx64.efi.old

/boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft:
total 2
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 512 mag 14 01:25 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 512 mag 14 01:25 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 512 mag 14 01:25 Boot

/boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot:
total 2759
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     512 mag 14 01:25 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root     512 mag 14 01:25 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1350888 mag 14 01:25 bootmgfw.efi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       0 mag 13 17:02 bootmgfw.efi.grb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1350888 mag 14 01:24 bootmgr.efi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  121856 mag 13 17:02 bootx64.efi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       0 mag 13 17:02 bootx64.efi.grb

/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu:
total 120
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    512 mag  6 10:18 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root    512 mag 14 01:25 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 121856 mag 13 17:02 grubx64.efi
--------------
```

I will appreciate any guideline / help from you guys.

Thanks in advance,
B.

Answer (score 0):

First, your partition type codes are messed up. Your first three partitions are all flagged as [EFI System Partitions (ESPs),](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) but only the first one should be of that type. Your partition #2 should almost certainly be of "Microsoft Basic Data" type. I'm not sure about your partition #3. You can change partition type codes with `gdisk`, using its `t` option. Be sure to save your changes via the `w` option when you're done. In `gdisk`, change the type code for partition #2 to `0700`. I'm not sure about partition #3, though.

If changing the type code doesn't work, try using the [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) CD or USB flash drive. (You can get these from the [rEFInd downloads page](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html).) If you boot into rEFInd and it enables you to boot Windows, then install rEFInd using the Debian package or binary `.zip` file. This will supplement or bypass GRUB 2 (as you see fit) for booting Linux, and bypass GRUB for booting Windows.

Comment: fixed...thnx, still does not boot into win8...

Answer (score 0):

I have to say it is very frustrating to see all the these tools (boot-repair, rEFInd, etc.) being recommended over and over and again and again, while the cause is unclear and the actual issues being treated like witchcraft.

Food for thought: Running 100 tools while not understanding the issue, might in some cases solve your problem, but might also not solve your problem or **make things worse**.

---

You are right, apart from the multiple EFI System Partitions your setup is missing some files. A proper setup looks like this:

```
livewire@za21:~$ ll /media/livewire/Windows\ 8/EFI/
insgesamt 12
drwx------ 1 livewire livewire     0 Jan 28 09:13 ./
drwx------ 1 livewire livewire 12288 Mai 16 03:11 ../
drwx------ 1 livewire livewire     0 Jan 28 09:13 Boot/
drwx------ 1 livewire livewire     0 Jan 27 22:31 Microsoft/
livewire@za21:~$ ll /media/livewire/Windows\ 8/EFI/Boot/
insgesamt 1324
drwx------ 1 livewire livewire       0 Jan 28 09:13 ./
drwx------ 1 livewire livewire       0 Jan 28 09:13 ../
-rw------- 1 livewire livewire 1354480 Jul 26  2012 bootx64.efi
livewire@za21:~$ ll /media/livewire/Windows\ 8/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/
insgesamt 4044
drwx------ 1 livewire livewire    8192 Jan 28 09:13 ./
drwx------ 1 livewire livewire       0 Jan 27 22:31 ../
-rw------- 1 livewire livewire   40960 Jan 28 09:13 BCD
-rw------- 1 livewire livewire   36864 Jan 28 09:13 BCD.LOG
-rw------- 2 livewire livewire       0 Jan 28 09:13 BCD.LOG1
-rw------- 2 livewire livewire       0 Jan 28 09:13 BCD.LOG2
drwx------ 1 livewire livewire       0 Jan 28 09:13 bg-BG/
-rw------- 1 livewire livewire 1354480 Jul 26  2012 bootmgfw.efi
-rw------- 1 livewire livewire 1350896 Jul 26  2012 bootmgr.efi
-rw------- 1 livewire livewire   65536 Jan 27 22:07 BOOTSTAT.DAT
-rw------- 1 livewire livewire    4186 Jun 27  2012 boot.stl
drwx------ 1 livewire livewire       0 Jan 28 09:13 cs-CZ/
drwx------ 1 livewire livewire       0 Jan 28 09:13 da-DK/
drwx------ 1 livewire livewire       0 Jan 28 09:13 de-DE/
drwx------ 1 livewire livewire       0 Jan 28 09:13 el-GR/
drwx------ 1 livewire livewire       0 Jan 28 09:13 en-GB/
drwx------ 1 livewire livewire       0 Jan 28 09:13 en-US/
drwx------ 1 livewire livewire       0 Jan 28 09:13 es-ES/
drwx------ 1 livewire livewire       0 Jan 28 09:13 et-EE/
drwx------ 1 livewire livewire       0 Jan 28 09:13 fi-FI/
drwx------ 1 livewire livewire    4096 Jan 28 09:13 Fonts/
drwx------ 1 livewire livewire       0 Jan 28 09:13 fr-FR/
drwx------ 1 livewire livewire       0 Jan 28 09:13 hr-HR/
drwx------ 1 livewire livewire       0 Jan 28 09:13 hu-HU/
drwx------ 1 livewire livewire       0 Jan 28 09:13 it-IT/
drwx------ 1 livewire livewire       0 Jan 28 09:13 ja-JP/
drwx------ 1 livewire livewire       0 Jan 28 09:13 ko-KR/
drwx------ 1 livewire livewire       0 Jan 28 09:13 lt-LT/
drwx------ 1 livewire livewire       0 Jan 28 09:13 lv-LV/
-rw------- 1 livewire livewire 1263856 Jul 26  2012 memtest.efi
drwx------ 1 livewire livewire       0 Jan 28 09:13 nb-NO/
drwx------ 1 livewire livewire       0 Jan 28 09:13 nl-NL/
drwx------ 1 livewire livewire       0 Jan 28 09:13 pl-PL/
drwx------ 1 livewire livewire       0 Jan 28 09:13 pt-BR/
drwx------ 1 livewire livewire       0 Jan 28 09:13 pt-PT/
drwx------ 1 livewire livewire    4096 Jan 28 09:13 qps-ploc/
drwx------ 1 livewire livewire       0 Jan 28 09:13 Resources/
drwx------ 1 livewire livewire       0 Jan 28 09:13 ro-RO/
drwx------ 1 livewire livewire       0 Jan 28 09:13 ru-RU/
drwx------ 1 livewire livewire       0 Jan 28 09:13 sk-SK/
drwx------ 1 livewire livewire       0 Jan 28 09:13 sl-SI/
drwx------ 1 livewire livewire       0 Jan 28 09:13 sr-Latn-CS/
drwx------ 1 livewire livewire       0 Jan 28 09:13 sv-SE/
drwx------ 1 livewire livewire       0 Jan 28 09:13 tr-TR/
drwx------ 1 livewire livewire       0 Jan 28 09:13 uk-UA/
drwx------ 1 livewire livewire       0 Jan 28 09:13 zh-CN/
drwx------ 1 livewire livewire       0 Jan 28 09:13 zh-HK/
drwx------ 1 livewire livewire       0 Jan 28 09:13 zh-TW/
```

The language resources are not that important for basic boot functionality, but `bootmgfw.efi`, `bootmgr.efi`, `BOOTSTAT.DAT` and `BCD`. One of the latter files (it must be `BCD`, because a GUID like string is clearly visible among other data when I put the file in an editor) contains configuration data (e.g. which partition to use for boot) and needs to be generated, which is the rather tricky part as I only know the Windows command for doing that. The other files are easy to find as they are stored in `C:\Windows\Boot\` on typical installations.

If you're lucky you'll find a working MBR (`C:\Boot\`) or EFI (`C:\EFI\`) boot configuration on the Windows 8 partition or the Windows boot partition that can be booted by GRUB. For booting the MBR configuration I recommend installing Ubuntu in MBR mode to a USB stick, booting it and let GRUB os-prober find the configuration to boot Windows and fix the issue in Windows. For EFI you can write a custom GRUB entry. Read my comment on: [Grub errors during UEFI dual boot for Windows 8 (can't find command 'drivemap')](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221311/grub-errors-during-uefi-dual-boot-for-windows-8-cant-find-command-drivemap/225435#comment371035_225435)

From within Windows you can reinstall the EFI boot loader and configuration to the location of your choice with `bcdboot C:\Windows /s C: /f uefi`. In this case `/s C:` will install to `C:`, you should replace it with the drive letter of the ESP you want to use.

Comment: thnx for reply... i actually used testdisk and restored my lost  partitions defs with success, used then bootxxx from win8 in order to recreate / fix boot sector but it did not help with booting win8 from grub2,... as well as boot-repair wasn't able to repair it... now I will try your suggestions with bcdxxx from within win8... thnx! b.