# unable to boot in windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8

I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 and I can't boot in Windows 8, I can only boot in the recovery.
Before that, I installed fedora over a Ubuntu installation and I was having the same problem.

Here is my boot-repair information : http://paste.ubuntu.com/5669119/

What can I do? I've tried everything that I could find.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are booting in UEFI mode and GRUB os-prober generated MBR boot entries giving you errors like "can't find command drivemap". I recommend creating a custom GRUB boot entry as described here: [Grub errors during UEFI dual boot for Windows 8 (can't find command 'drivemap')](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221311/grub-errors-during-uefi-dual-boot-for-windows-8-cant-find-command-drivemap)

Entry would probably look like this:

```
menuentry "Windows 8 (custom entry) (on /dev/sda6)" --class windows --class os {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod fat
        insmod chain
    set root='(hd0,gpt6)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 921B-0709
    chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
```