# Windows 8 overwrites boot with Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, uefi

I have a Sony VAIO S series with Windows 8 preinstalled and then I  installed Ubuntu 12.10  partition.

The first time I was booting the Grub appeared, and I was able to choose between Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.10. The problem is that when I select Windows 8 the Grub doesn't appear anymore and it boots always on Windows.

I read a bout this command in a Windows command prompt:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

Seems like the command worked in the sense that you can see again the purple Grub menu at boot, and it also works when you select Ubuntu however, if you select to boot Windows 8 from Grub, you get the following two errors:

```
error: can't find command 'drivemap'
error: invalid EFI file path.
```

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221311/grub-errors-during-uefi-dual-boot-for-windows-8-cant-find-command-drivemap) (possible duplicate - please check)

Comment: See this - [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/q/221835), and make sure you followed it correctly.Most probably secure boot is causing the problem.

Comment: I already try with both solutions when I repair the boot from ubuntu im able to select again between ubuntu and windows but then after selecting windows it overwrites the boot and I cant select Ubuntu...any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dual-boot Ubuntu 12.10 on UEFI along Windows 8 (GRUB - error: can't find command drivemap)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/233687/dual-boot-ubuntu-12-10-on-uefi-along-windows-8-grub-error-cant-find-command)